# How do I pass an array to a template and then show the content in Play Framework?

Tags: arrays, templates, groovy, parameters, playframework

Previously I have only used the Scala templates, but now am I using Java and the Groovy templates. I find it hard to understand the Groovy templates.

I pass an array from my controller to the view like this:

```
UserRecord[] users = {new UserRecord(1,"Jonas"), new UserRecord(2,"Anders")};
render(users);
```

Now, how to I create a Groovy template that receives the array and then print them in a list?

I have tried with the code below, but it doesn't work, no users are listed:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Users</h1>

<ul>
    #{list users:users, as:'user' }
        </li>${user.name}</li>
    #{/list}
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The `list` tag takes either an `items` parameter to specify what to iterate over, or the first positional argument.](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/tags#list)

So `#{list users:users, as:'user'}` should be either `#{list items:users, as:'user'}` or just `#{list users, as:'user'}`.

Comment: Ah, this works on collections, but not on arrays so I will user ArrayLists instead, thanks.